# use dynamic values instead of hard coded

Tags: shell, scripting, xilinx

I have a file which got details of server and databases in below format:

```
server1,server2|server3,server4|db1,db2,db5|db3,db4,db6
```

and I need to display the same in below format. Output:

```
source db is db1 and target db is db3
source db is db2 and target db is db4
source db is db5 and target db is db6
```

Currently I am using the below code and able to get the desired result:

```
for id in `cat file.txt | cut -d "|" -f3-4`
do
echo $id
var1=$(echo $id | cut -d "|" -f1 | cut -d "," -f1)
var2=$(echo $id | cut -d "|" -f1 | cut -d "," -f2)
var3=$(echo $id | cut -d "|" -f1 | cut -d "," -f3)
var4=$(echo $id | cut -d "|" -f2 | cut -d "," -f1)
var5=$(echo $id | cut -d "|" -f2 | cut -d "," -f2)
var6=$(echo $id | cut -d "|" -f2 | cut -d "," -f3)
echo "source db is $var1 and target db is $var4"
echo "source db is $var2 and target db is $var5"
echo "source db is $var3 and target db is $var6"
done
```

However in some of the lines, the number of source and target databases are different, say some lines have 1 db only and some have 5 or 6 databases list, in which the above code does not work to list all the databases or blank output in few lines if have databases less than 3.

Is there any way that I could turn the code into dynamic, so that as per the number of source and target databases, I could generate the output.

Comment: What does this have to do with Xilinx?

Answer (score 0):

was able to accomplish the required result using below code:

```
var=$(cat file.txt | awk -F "|" '{print $3F}' | awk --field-separator="," "{ print NF }")
for id in `cat file.txt | cut -d "|" -f3-4`
do
    for id2 in `seq $var`
    do
        var1=$(echo $id | cut -d "|" -f1 | cut -d "," -f$id2)
        var2=$(echo $id | cut -d "|" -f2 | cut -d "," -f$id2)
        echo "source db is $var1 and target db is $var2"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in bash. It will print "none" when DB is missing from source or destination.

```
while read line
do
    src_len=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3 | awk -F',' '{print NF}'`
    dest_len=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f4 | awk -F',' '{print NF}'`
    if test `expr $src_len - $dest_len` -ge 0
    then
        for i in `seq $src_len`
        do
            echo "source db is `echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3 | cut -d',' -f${i}` and target db is `echo $line | cut -d'|' -f4 | awk -F',' -v i=$i '{print $i ? $i : "none"}'`"
        done
    else
        for i in `seq $dest_len`
        do
            echo "source db is `echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3 | awk -F',' -v i=$i '{print $i ? $i : "none"}'` and target db is `echo $line | cut -d'|' -f4 | cut -d',' -f${i}`"
        done
    fi
done < <(cat file.txt)
```

Comment: bash can do arithmetic, no need to call out to `expr`; in bash use `[[...]]` instead of `test`; that's a useless use of cat, use `done < file.txt`; use `$(...)` instead of backticks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain bash with no external tools:

```sh
max() { echo "$(( $1 < $2 ? $2 : $1 ))"; }

while IFS='|' read -r s1 s2 d1 d2; do
  IFS=, read -ra d1s <<<"$d1"
  IFS=, read -ra d2s <<<"$d2"
  for ((i=0; i < $(max ${#d1s[@]} ${#d2s[@]}); i++)); do
    printf "source db is %s and target db is %s\n" "${d1s[i]:-na}" "${d2s[i]:-na}"
  done
done < file.txt
```

With this input file:

```
$ cat file.txt
server1,server2|server3,server4|db1,db2,db5|db3,db4,db6
server11,server12|server13,server14|db11,db12,db15|db13
server21,server22|server23,server24|db21|db23,db24,db26
```

the output is

```
source db is db1 and target db is db3
source db is db2 and target db is db4
source db is db5 and target db is db6
source db is db11 and target db is db13
source db is db12 and target db is na
source db is db15 and target db is na
source db is db21 and target db is db23
source db is na and target db is db24
source db is na and target db is db26
```

---

Perl will be faster than bash, if your file is large. This uses the CPAN module List::MoreUtils:

```sh
perl -e '
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use List::MoreUtils qw( pairwise );
    use vars qw( $a $b );
    while (<>) {
        chomp;
        my @fields = split /[|]/;
        my @d1 = split /,/, $fields[2];
        my @d2 = split /,/, $fields[3];
        pairwise {
            printf "source db is %s and target db is %s\n",
                $a // "na",
                $b // "na"
        } @d1, @d2;
    }
' file.txt
```